# AlchemyAPI for Concept Insights's Conceptual Search

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, concept-insights

Concept Insights has been deprecated, is there any function in AlchemyAPI or other Watson product that can perform Concept Insights's Conceptual Search function (http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/concept-insights/api/v2/?java#conceptual_search)?

That is given document ID to return documents from corpus that are similar?

Comment: Would love to know the same. I see AlchemyAPI has a concept tagging feature. But cant find any docs (or migration docs) discussing how to achieve the same features with AlchemyAPI

Answer (score 0):

The Conceptual Search function from the deprecated Concept Insights service is currently not available in the AlchemyAPI service or another Watson service. Bluemix is always looking for features and enhancements to the platform and its services. If possible, please submit a request through the IBM Bluemix Ideas site (https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas) and explain how this function benefited you. Ideas that are submitted through the IBM Bluemix Ideas site are regularly reviewed by the Project Management Teams.